# Обработчик inline-кнопки aiogram

Tags: aiogram, бот, inline

Пишу бота для тг. Что-то вроде викторины. Как сделать так, чтобы сначала бот отправлял первый вопрос, после нажатия кнопки, удалял первый вопрос и присылал второй и тд?

```
async def test2(message : types.Message):
count_img = 0
while count_img < 5:
    n = await sqlite_db.sql_img()
    if n not in img:
        img.append(n)
        count_img+=1

name = await sqlite_db.sql_name()
list_name=[]
for ret in name:
    ret = re.sub(r"[()'',\[\]]", "", str(ret))
    list_name.append(ret)
for l in range(5):
    n1 = sqlite_db.cur.execute('SELECT name FROM actress WHERE IMG =?', (img[l],)).fetchall()
    n1 = re.sub(r"[()'',\[\]]", "", str(n1))
    print(n1)
    list_name2=[]
    list_name2.append(str(n1))
    count_name = 0
    while count_name < 3:
        r = random.choice(list_name)
        if r not in list_name2:
            list_name2.append(r)
            count_name+=1
    print(list_name2)
    random.shuffle(list_name2)
    print(list_name2)
    client = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    b = []
    for i in range(len(list_name2)):
        if list_name2[i] == n1:
            b.append(InlineKeyboardButton(f'{list_name2[i]}', callback_data=f'name_5'))
        else:
            b.append(InlineKeyboardButton(f'{list_name2[i]}', callback_data=f'name_{i}'))
    await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, img[l])
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text = 'Кто она?', reply_markup=client.add(b[0],b[1]).add(b[2],b[3]))
```

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(startswith='name_'))
async def name_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    result = 0
    res = int(callback.data.split('_')[1])
    if res == 5:
        result += 1
        print('Правильно ',result)
    else:
        print('No Правильно ', result)
    await callback.answer(res)
    await callback.answer()
```

Answer (score 1):

Итак, для того что вы хотите сделать, вам нужно сделать машину состояний. Читайте код снизу.

```py
from aiogram import executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

# это я тут прячу токен бота не обращай внимания
from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
# для машины состояний нужно место где она будет хранить состояние и данные которые мы хотим сохранить (временно)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


# создаем такой вот класс который наследуется от StatesGroup
# в нем мы можем создать некие состояния которые мы можем менять
# и в зависимости от этого состояния решать какие хендлеры будут работать а какие нет
# ps название класса(состояний) может быть любым
class RandomNameForStateClass(StatesGroup):
    # да и состояние может быть любым. Как и их количество
    random_name_for_state = State()
    insert_name = State()


# для удобства и минимализации кода старт будет запускать наше состояние, которое создает инлайн кнопки
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def handler(msg: types.Message):
    # запускаем стейт / хоть и не обязательно позже напишу почему
    await RandomNameForStateClass.random_name_for_state.set()
    # теперь нужно сделать первый вопрос c кнопками
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка1", callback_data="but_1"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка2", callback_data="but_2")
    )
    await msg.answer("Выбери одну из кнопок, и текст поменяется!", reply_markup=markup)


# а теперь делаем хендлер который ловит нажатие
# для упрощения он ловит обе кнопки и реагирует одинково
# если мы запустили стейт очень важно указывать его в декораторе иначе наш хендлер будет игнорировать все что имеет
# стейт и будет внимателен только к колбеку который начинает с but_
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="but_", state=RandomNameForStateClass.random_name_for_state)
async def but_pressed(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    # и вот когда кнопка нажмется, ЭТОТ хендлер сработает так как callback_data обоих кнопок начинается с but_
    # на этом этапе мы можем к примеру получить данные которые ввел/нажал юезр
    # конкретно в этом случае у нас есть callback_data которая лежит в call.data она будет равна but_1 или but_2
    # давайте в зависимости от этого что-то напишем
    call_data = call.data
    # тут я просто разделил строку but_1/2 по нижнему подчеркиванию и получил список из but и 1/2
    but_press = call_data.split("_")[1]
    # а вот это некое хранилище которое дает нам FSM
    # по идее мы можем его открыть и без запуска стейта
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["but_1_question"] = but_press
    # дальше мы просто меняем предыдущий месседж, который у нас сейчас находится в переменной call
    await call.message.edit_text("Я же говорил текст поменяется! Но кнопки я не дам! Напиши что-то")
    # ну и здесь меняем стейт
    await RandomNameForStateClass.insert_name.set()
    # а вот такую штуку нужно делать только в колбек хендлерах
    # она нужны чтобы телеграмм понял что мы обработали колбек и убрал часики возле иноайн кнопки
    await call.answer()


# теперь для разнообразия заставим юзера что-то написать и потом напомним ему какую он кнопку нажимал
@dp.message_handler(state=RandomNameForStateClass.insert_name)
async def but_pressed(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # к слову data которую мы тут взяли это по факту словарь и к нему применяются те же методы
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        but_presseds = data.get("but_1_question")
    await msg.answer("Ух ты ты что-то написал!"
                     "О я тут решил напомнить тебе какую кнопку ты нажал, и я вытащил её из стейта!"
                     "Предаставляешь я умею хранить информацию!"
                     f"Ты нажал кнопка {but_presseds}")
    # ну и если мы закончили то стейт закрываем
    # НООО не забудь забрать данные из него если они нужны иначе они будут утеряны
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Ну и в целом можно было даже обойтись без состояний если вы намерены использовать исключительно инлайн кнопки без того чтобы заставлять юзера вводить какие-либо данные (текст картинки) и делать хендлеры исходя из колбек даты.

Comment: Я поняла, что Вы сделали у себя, но мне нужно не совсем то. У меня в хендлере составляются 5 вопросов(картинка и 4 варианта ответов кнопками), я хочу, чтобы бот прислал 1 вопрос. После того, как пользователь ответит на первый вопрос, бот присылает второй и так далее. Я не совсем понимаю, как мне Ваш пример изменить под себя.
И ещё вопрос, возможно ли кнопку сделать не кликабельной? То есть вопрос "Кто она?" я хочу сделать кнопкой, чтобы не сильно выделялось на фоне инлайн клавиатуры

Comment: @Мария ну такс если кратко то при каждом нажатии кнопки вы должны их ловить и просто менять текст предыдущего сообщения вместе с кнопками. Вы должны просто на каждый следующий вопрос либо менять стейт либо делать это через колбек дату которую вы делаете для кнопки. Насчет второго вопроса, в целом если у кнопки отсутствует какой-нибудь хендлер то она не будет срабатывать.